# Flash Pdf viewer just like scribd

Tags: flash

is there any free flash pdf viewer so that i can embeded it in my asp pages,i tried searching google but all in vain.[embedded PDF viewer will also work ]

thanks in advance

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just supply the PDF as a download and let the browser launch the Acrobat reader (if installed)? Can you tell us more about what you are trying to achieve, there may be a better solution than an embedded PDF viewer (which is still going to need downloading and/or installing).

Comment: i dont want to use frames so i tried using embeded tag to embeded the pfp in my asp page.it gives me access is denied error,i dont know what it is throwing this error.embedded PDF viewer will also work

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Flex Paper** -- http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/

As of 6/29/2011 there is a GPLv3 version with logo, and a Commercial version. It can run stand-alone, or be downloaded as a SWC library to embed in your own Flex application.

Comment: Flexpaper works great. You can customize the controls, It has a beautiful output and yes, if you put some tricks on, you can mix the flipboard and imagemagick to create any flip pages you want.

Answer (score 6):

**Scribd** has their own proprietary Flash PDF Viewer called **iPaper**. The commercial product from Adobe is called [FlashPaper](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashpaper/). There are no free alternatives to that. So embedding is your closest option.

The embed tag is very simple:

```
<embed src="MyPdfDocument.pdf" width="500" height="375" />
```

Here's an [example](http://blogs.adobe.com/pdfdevjunkie/2007/08/using_the_html_embed_tag_to_di.html) of how that looks.

Comment: thanks for your answer but i have tried it before and acrobat reader gives me access is denied error [this file is located on a server]
it works fine when opened with direct url,do you know the cause of the error ?

Comment: i found the corect syntax
<embed width="800" height="500" wmode="opaque" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" quality="high" src="FAQ'sonSurvanta.pdf#toolbar=0&navpanes=0"/>

Answer (score 2):

What about www.embedit.in ?

Answer (score 2):

I know it is a bit late, but this can be useful for people that come here from searches.
ZViewer is a pdf file viewer based on swftools:
http://swfviewer.blogspot.com/

Comment: I know its late, any ways thanks a lot. You have given me one more option. : )

Answer (score 1):

I've http://issuu.com/ which looks like just the ticket for what you're after

The best feature (for my project) is that it loads the PDFs 5 pages at a time, so getting the flash reader to try to display a 30Mb 200 page PDF won't mean loads of bandwidth