# Flash pdf viewer

Tags: php, jquery, flash, pdf

Is there a flash pdf viewer (with php script) that dynamically converts pdf documents on upload to flash for viewing.

**It must be possible to host this solution myself on my shared hosting.**

Open source is prefered but if you know for commercial one it is OK too.

If you suggest pdf2swf for conversion from http://www.swftools.org/ and flexpaper from http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/ for viewing then explain me how to install pdf2swf on a share linux hosting plan (or point me for instructions).

Thank You.

Comment: There's a similar question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/781352/flash-pdf-viewer-just-like-scribd

Comment: That question is about viewer and this one is about viewer that dynamically convert...or how to install pdf2swf on shared hosting a whole different beast. so if you have a solution...