# FOSS Flash based multi file format viewer

Tags: flash, pdf, web, ms-word

Firstly this question has been asked a while back, and given the time there are probably newer options and improvements.

[Flash pdf viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736215/flash-pdf-viewer)

Googling seems to offer a number of tools that are a combination of executable that converts to a base format and an accompanying viewer.

http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/docs.htm

> To make it possible for your users to view your PDF documents without
>   using Acrobat Reader, documents first needs to be converted to the SWF
>   file format. There is a range of available converters, both commercial
>   and free. The following example uses the open source tool SwfTools and
>   can be automated if needed.

This solution does not work well for me as i would like to skip the intermediate step and simply have the flash viewer run in the browser and suck the original file down for display.

I am particularly interested in the well following formats with others a bonus.

- word
- pdf
- powerpoint

I am hoping to avoid using a pdf -> html conversion tool such as itext but it might have to be a last fallback option.

**WHY Flash and not HTML ?**

Part of the motivation for asking for a Flash based solution is that there does not appear to be any ready to go framework that spits out a HTML form. I was hoping to keep the solution completely browser based. Prompting the user to download and then open in something like Office or free equivalents is not practical or allowed.

**What about the Acrobat plugin for PDFs**

The primary reason for not taking the easy route and simply making use of a acrobat plugin is many plain suck and they suck hard. They have a tendency to lockup and take out your browser. I know there are some browsers that run things in isolation. This isolation may save other sessions but that still does not solve the problem of the current session.

Comment: I'm curious about the use case for this. Users of propriety software already have Acrobat+Office as content handlers and FOSS users have Evince+LibreOffice. You seem to be trying to bypass the user's choice of tools which is actually counter to FOSS philosophy and likely to give 90% of users a worse experience. For the other 10% providing an alternate download in another format (even degraded) should normally be sufficient. So why the Flash viewer?

Comment: Most PDF viewers such as the Adobe Acrobat plugin suck mainly because you never know when its going to crash and it does crash often. I was hoping to only use just the browser. There are always other options if introduces other foss non browser solutions.

Comment: I've found Foxit (Windows) and Evince (linux) provide viable end-user alternatives for people having problems with Acrobat. Of course that doesn't help you, as the content provider, but I wonder if you might be taking too much responsibility for what is ultimately a SEP (Somebody Else's Problem). Put in another context, do you care that much if your end-users are having problems viewing your site in IE 3.0 ? Your content is valid, are you responsible for their broken tools?

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the stated method of *converting the files(doc,ppt,pdf) to an intermediate format(swf) and then display it* I don't think there is any other alternative. In my knowledge, no such open source flash viewer exists that can directly display a pdf/doc file without converting it to flash format.

However, is it really necessary to display documents in flash format? Recently, I came across a site fileslap.com that converts these documents into png image and then displays it.

Doc file : http://fileslap.com/20/consultants.doc

PDF File : http://fileslap.com/F/HTML_Cheat_Sheet.pdf

PDF to png conversion can be done using ImageMagick but I have no idea how he is converting doc to png.

**The best option right now is to use Google Docs Viewer in your project (https://docs.google.com/viewer)
Just upload the file on your site and embed the player in an iframe with source link in this format**

**http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://mysite.com/path/file.doc**

Note:You don't need to give google your file. You can keep it at your server or anywhere accessible on net through a url.

Edit: FileSlap is also using Google Doc Viewer.

```
<div class="doc"> 
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://media.dropdo.com.s3.amazonaws.com/20/consultants.doc&embedded=true" width="89%" height="700" style="border: none;"></iframe> 
</div>
```

Comment: You seriously have no idea? Open it in Word, take a screenshot.

Comment: @gladoscc ... and save it as a .png file. Well, I hope it was an attempt to be sarcastic but we are talking about doing it programmatically not manually. If there is a way to programmatically open a word file on linux, take screenshots of each page and save them as png files, do let me know. :)

Comment: Running Word via ActiveX opening and taking screenshots or printing it into a png or whatever is not scalable, and its very much susceptable to hanging and does not play well if at all to handling multiple simulatenous requests.

Comment: By giving a url, Google must download the file so it can convert to a png. THey do have a copy during the process, and given they keep records of everything for data mining, and that there is no definitive comment from them that they dont keep their own copy, you really have missed the point of privacy.

Answer (score 0):

It's not OSS, but embedding the [Google Docs Viewer](http://docs.google.com/viewer) would get you plenty of document types and skips the intermediate conversion.

Comment: Thats a horrible solution, unfortunately most users are not happy giving Google their PDF even if its just to view.

Comment: I believe Google Docs viewer converts it to a PNG file too.

Comment: How GD displays the PDF is immaterial, the very act of sharing your PDF with them is not always acceptable.