# show pdf files in a php page

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-viewer

I have some pdf files and want to show them online in my website,not downloading or displaying with acrobat or firefox add-on, actullay I need a pdf viewer. I am not sure if there ia any prepared library or plugin. I guess I have to convert each page of pdf to an image file,but how can I do it?

thank you.

Comment: Most of the modern browsers have this functionality built-in.

Comment: I know that.But I need something like scribd.com pdf viewer.

Comment: 138 of 210 answers accepted? Mate, do not expect your questions to attract too much attention...

Answer (score 6):

Like @Lix said most modern browsers have this built in it works well in chrome and firefox. This is what I do...

```
<object height="950" data="sample-report.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="860">

            <p>It appears you don't have a PDF plugin for this browser.
                No biggie... you can <a href="sample-report.pdf">click here to
                download the PDF file.</a>
            </p>

        </object>
```

It degrades well if the browser doesn't support viewing PDF by letting one download it. I have looked for other solutions such as converting to html or image. But I don't like to load lots of large images and converting to html loses much of the formatting.

You can convert on your server though if your running linux with this command...

convert abc.pdf abc.jpg

-EDIT--
Firefox uses [PDF.js](http://mozilla.github.com/pdf.js/) to render PDFs. I've looked into before, but the complexity wasn't worth it for any of my projects.

Hope this helps. Aloha.

Comment: I forgot to mention [pdf.js](http://mozilla.github.com/pdf.js/) that's what Mozilla uses to render PDF in firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/

and the similar question

[Flash Pdf viewer just like scribd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/781352/flash-pdf-viewer-just-like-scribd)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to view your files in google docs viewer in an iframe:

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://www.example.com/yourPDFfile.pdf" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```