# html pdf object tag - parameters not working

Tags: html, object, internet-explorer-9, embed, adobe-reader

In a simple html object tag like this:

```
<object data='Calendar2012_2013.pdf#page=2' 
        type='application/pdf' 
        width='90%' 
        height='1000px'>

<p>It appears your Web browser is not configured to display PDF files. 
No worries, just <a href='p.pdf'>click here to download the PDF file.</a></p>

</object>
```

I am trying to get the page to show on page 2 on default but on default page 1 still shows. Does anyone know whats wrong?

EDIT: it seems to work with firefox but I need it to work with IE9...

Answer (score 0):

Firefox uses PDF.js to display PDF. Chrome does something similar. I think with IE9 you are stuck with converting to an image or some kind of javascript plugin. I responded to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12551287/show-pdf-files-in-a-php-page/12551342#12551342) the other day

Answer (score 0):

```
<object type="application/pdf" width="90%" height="1000px">
   <param name="src" value="/Calendar2012_2013.pdf#page=2" />
   <p>It appears your Web browser is not configured to display PDF files.
      No worries, just <a href="p.pdf">click here to download the PDF file.</a>
   </p>
</object>
```

try the above code.