# Link to open PDF from folder

Tags: html, hyperlink

I have some PDF's sitting in a folder on my computer, is there a way to write a link to open them on to a webpage?

The main idea is when the site goes live the link will be used to download the pdfs from the folder, but obviously at a later stage the folder will be a temp folder on my website.

So at the moment i just want to open the pdfs from a link, and the final goal will be to have the links download them.

Can any one help me?

This is the file path to get to the pdf i want to link to.

C:\Users\Shaun\Documents\FormValue\CS1.pdf

How would i create the link?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to have a link to a PDF, you just have to put the relative path to the file in the `href` attribute of an `a` tag. So let's say you had a folder called `pdfs`, with the file `boom.pdf` inside it, and folder called `site` sitting beside it, with the file `site.html` in it.  Then all you'd have to do is put this link in the html file:

```
<a href="../pdfs/boom.pdf">Link to a pdf</a>
```

In most (all?) browsers now a days, that will open the PDF in a new tab.  To download it you would right-click it and do the `Save Link As` thing.  Just need to get the path in `href` right.

---

**UPDATE**

If you want to use the full path to the file, you need to prefix it with `file://`.  Then you just put it in the href the same as with a regular link, ending up with something like:

```
<a href="file://C:\Users\Shaun\Documents\FormValue\CS1.pdf">Link to a pdf</a>
```

This should work with your set up, but if the pdf and the html files are stored near each other, relative URLs are still a good option. A little bit of Google work should show you how to write those.

Comment: I tried this and it create a underlined peace of text saying Link to pdf in blue, so it looked like a link but did not do anything when i clicked on it, see my edit to see the file path im trying to connect to

Comment: @Pommy Added a bit about how to use the full path you gave.

Answer (score 3):

For each PDF just do what I talk about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12551287/show-pdf-files-in-a-php-page/12551342#12551342).

```
<object height="950" data="sample-report.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="860">
  <p>It appears you don't have a PDF plugin for this browser.
    No biggie... you can <a href="sample-report.pdf">click here to
    download the PDF file.</a>
  </p>
</object>
```

It works with most browsers and it degrades nicely.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like youre asking if you can put a link on a web site to a PDF sitting on your computer. You can't. The files have to be either on another web site or on your site's server.

Comment: Ok Thanks that's helps me alot, The website is not live, but when it is there will be a temp file that i want to grab the pdfs out of, is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ASP.NET, you can have the link point to a handler that accepts a query string identifying the file, either by file name or a hash of the file. Then the handler can look in the folder for a file that matches the pattern, read the file as a byte array, and then write those bytes to HttpResponse.