# Using Razor to download file from html <a> attribute

Tags: c#, html, razor

I am currently adding a notification for our customers. They should be able to download a `pdf` with list of our branches. When I click on the link nothing happens. I don't understand why. I'm using standard MVC approach. I tried to look at the path that is stored in the variable and the file exists there.

Anything I'm missing here?

Edit:

when opening the link in new tab chrome puts "about:blank#blocked" in url (popups enabled)

Thanks for any input

```
@{
   var path = Server.MapPath(@"~/ToolsModule/Content/Forms/PdfTemplates/PBS/ListOfBranches.pdf");
 }

<div>
   <div>you can find a link to list of all branches <a href="@path"><b>here</b></a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: When you see the page source what value(s) do you see in your `a` tag? Are they correctly being formed to take you to your pdf file?

Comment: Yes - I've put breakpoint on the variable and its value is "C:\\WORKSPACE\\PFS\\FiP20Web\\FiP20\\Source\\DEV\\FIP20App\\FIP2Web\\ToolsModule\\Content\\Forms\\PdfTemplates\\PBS\\ListOfBranches.pdf", after replacing \\with \, it goes to the file

Comment: If you want to use the full path to the file, you need to prefix it with file://. Then you just put it in the href the same as with a regular link, ending up with something like: `<a href="file://C:\\WORKSPACE\\PFS\\FiP20Web\\FiP20\\Source\\DEV\\FIP20App\\FIP2Web\\ToolsModule\\Content\\Forms\\PdfTemplates\\PBS\\ListOfBranches.pdf">Link to a pdf</a>`

Comment: @RahulSharma - thanks for the advice, but i don't think that is correct - I tried but to no avail + I need the path to be relative, not absolute

Comment: Take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12728411/link-to-open-pdf-from-folder

Comment: thanks - I tried to debug the same thing in IE and it works - I dont know why it doesn't in chrome tho

Comment: Maybe it can be because of this: https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/4590954?hl=en