# How can I launch a .pdf with acrobat reader in windows from a HTML document?

Tags: html, c++, pdf, acrobat, wtl

I am developing a system which consists of two parts. A backend in C++ using WTL and a Frontend in HTML/Javascript, using the IE Controllers available in the Windows Template Library.

At some point I need the user to be able to open a documentation file in .pdf format from the HTML document. Is this possible? I don't want the document to be displayed on the html document window itself. It is preferably to be opened on a separate windows by the native .pdf reader.

Any suggestions?

Comment: is a separate tab in the browser for the pdf an acceptable option?

Comment: @ArnonZilca no it is not, I can only have one window (one tab) in the IE control.

Comment: I see. Did you try the `object` tag (shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12551287/show-pdf-files-in-a-php-page/12551342#12551342))? What are the results and how do they differ from the behavior you're looking for?

Comment: I tried the object tag before but it leads me to the .pdf being shown on the HTML document itself, the behaviour I'm looking for is to "click on a link" and then open the acrobat reader application for the .pdf document.

Comment: ok. What about creating an `href` with the html5 [download](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp) attribute: `<a href="http://..." download="FileName">Download it!</a>`. Other then that, I think that deciding to save/open/dialog is controlled by the browser's settings.