# How to restrict file from downloading by end user?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a project requirement that restrict downloading a file(video, pdf, doc, ppt file types)  from end users. End user can only view from my site but they can't able to download that file.

Comment: How, exactly, can your users view those file types on your site?

Comment: Yes, user can view those files, lets say user can able to view video on my site but they cannot download that video by anyway ... and i m using asp.net with c#

Comment: Again: how, exactly, can your users view those file types on your site?

Comment: You may need to build your own file viewer or find other third party tool which not allow to download content of files

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta: i m not sure... :)  but you can suggest me any tools and online viewer control that only view that file but restrict download of that file...

Comment: One of the example id youtube video streaming which allow you to see not to download

Comment: [Check this SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/781352/flash-pdf-viewer-just-like-scribd)

Comment: Please provide as many relevant specific details as possible. How will the files be viewed? What is your definition of downloading a file? What, if anything, have you tried?

Comment: @Igby Largeman: dowloading means saving file on their machine.... and i am really confuse from where to start! :)

Answer (score 4):

Since you mention asp.net, you would be serving the files over the web.
Video, pdf, doc and ppt files are downloaded to the client. The browser then launches the respective application so a user can view them.

If you are serving data in those formats, user will be able to save them.
You cannot stop a user from downloading them.

For formats like videos, you can stream them, making it difficult for a user to save them.
Ppt and docs can be converted and shown in an in-site html based viewer.  That way you can tell the browser not to cache the content, but the user would still be able to save the html pages.

Comment: Just look at Amazon's web-based kindle reader to proof the opposite ;-)

Comment: @UweKeim kindle reader doesn't send its data in application formats like pdf, doc or ppt. It gives you a web based html 5 reader. And you can save the page by page content if you go to the iframe inside the main page. Painfully difficult to save a whole book, but not impossible.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with following javascript function:

```
function checkButton(){
    if(event.button != 1){
        document.oncontextmenu=new Function ("return false") ;
        //if NS6
        if (window.sidebar){
            document.oncontextmenu=disableselect
        }
    }
}
```

This function disables your save as ability.

**For its referance , refer:**

http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?dotnet.12.592427.15

Comment: How would this, by itself, prevent an authorized user from downloading a given file?

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta It will prevent access to particular file.

Comment: To *unauthorized* users, sure. That's not what Hitesh is asking for, though. He's asking that a given user (authorized or not), who can *view* a file, be prevented from *downloading* it.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of way you can make it hard to download but not prevent is

1) Disable the right click on your web page ( You can not do it completely but at least will make it harder for normal user)

2) Dynamic create the URL path and make it invalid after sometime , so that end user find it very difficult to get it and download.